# UITableViewCell's background settings are reset on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell, indexpath

I have a UITableView Controller in my project. So I made a UITableViewCell setup like here:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Section: \(indexPath.section). Row: \(indexPath.row)."

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 1 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    }

    return cell
}
```

I want my tableview's cells to be gray if their index is not divisible by 2.

When tableview appears, everything is perfect! But when I scroll up and down, cells starts to change their colors to gray.

So at the end all my cells are gray.

Here are some images:

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE73g.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZHru.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add an `else` statement, since the cells are reused.

```
else {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!) It was so easy!) :D

Comment: @AlexVihlayev No problem mate. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you never set background back to white. Since cells are being reused, at some point you set gray for all of them. Instead you should check the row index every time cell is reused:

```
cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? UIColor.white : UIColor.gray
```

Answer (score 0):

Because tableview reuses the cell

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

cell.textLabel?.text = "Section: \(indexPath.section). Row: \(indexPath.row)."

if indexPath.row % 2 == 1 {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
}else{
    cell.backgroundColor = YOUR_COLOR
}
return cell
```

}

Edit : Gellert Lee answered it first and quite simple